# Laravel Eloquent groupBy()

Tags: laravel

In a table I want to get the patientNames grouping them based on appointmentDate. But is only returning me array of one value.

I tried:

```
$app = DB::table('appointment')->select('appointmentDate','patientName')
       ->where('doctorId',$id)
       ->groupBy('appointmentDate')->get();
```

I want all the patients groupedby the appointment date, but it gives me only one patient detail, though multiple patients have same appointmentDate.

Comment: What type of field is `appointmentDate` e.g,. `Date`, `DateTime`, `Timestamp` etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how sql group by works.

Try with orderBy instead, if you just need them sorted all by appointmentDate.

```
$app = DB::table('appointment')->select('appointmentDate','patientName')
   ->where('doctorId',$id)
   ->orderBy('appointmentDate')->get();
```

If you want all patients in separate arrays for each appointmentDate it's better to use Eloquents instead of DB select():

```
$app = Appointment::where('doctorId',$id)->get()->groupBy('appointmentDate');
```